# Django, Pulling a Value from a Model based on an ID

Tags: django

I'm relatively new to Django and as a test of my knowledge I'm trying to set up a project where it displays a list of games between anchor tags, when one of the game tags is clicked on, it pulls information about that game from a model using the ID (primary key) relative to that name. For instance the first games ID would be 1 and so on.

However, I am uncertain as to how to approach building a view for this. The only way I was able to get information from a template before was from user input (input tag) and then using request.GET to take the information from the input.

So far in this project, anchor tags are linking to a different URL which has the view which gets the information based on the id, then it should refresh the page and the information should display. Everything should be easy, but I'm just having trouble thinking of a way to get the id of the game based on which link is clicked. Is there a way I can simply set the value of this ID somewhere and reference it in the view, or rather pull the id of the game based on which link is clicked?

Code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} <!-- Extends the base models html design-->

{% block title %}Arcade{%  endblock  %}

{% block content %}

{% if games %}
<p>Found {{ games|length }} game{{ games|pluralize }}</p>
    {% for game in games %}
        <li><a href="details.html">{{ game.game_name }}</a></li><!--Game Link->
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>There are currently no games in the database.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if results %}


{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

I hope I did an adequate job explaining this problem.

To simplify it further: How do I pull any kind of value from a template?

Thank You

Keith

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. In each iteration of your for loop, you have an object called `game`, which is presumably a model instance. So you can just do:

```
<li><a href="/game/{{ game.id }}/">{{ game.game_name }}</a></li>
```

Or, even better, use the reverse URL functionality:

```
<li><a href="{% url game_details game.id %}">{{ game.game_name }}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using AJAX for this.

When the user clicks a tag, have the page asynchronously GET or POST to your django backend. If you want to GET, write a url to the effect of

> ^/data/game/(\d+)

then grab the id, get your model instance, and return some json or xml.